# Meaning of "That's gonna leave one helluva scar"

Tags: idioms

What does

> That's gonna leave one **helluva** scar

mean? Does *helluva* stand for *a hell off a*?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We appreciate added information about your question, such as what confused you when you researched the answer, etc. With more information, you're more likely to get a more helpful answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I didn't know the actual meaning of "hell off a" on that context.

Answer (score 6):

No. It is a representation of how people pronounce *hell of a*. (There is no phrase *hell off a* as far as I know).

Comment: It might also be called a phonetic spelling of certain regional U.S. accents.

Comment: It was obviously a typo! Minus 1 for being petty.

Comment: I'm a Ramblin' Wreck from Georgia Tech, and a hell of an engineer—
A helluva, helluva, helluva, helluva, hell of an engineer.
Like all the jolly good fellows, I drink my whiskey clear.
I'm a Ramblin' Wreck from Georgia Tech and a hell of an engineer. (Georgia Tech fight song, based ona Scottish drinking song)

Answer (score 1):

As @Coiln Fine said, it's based on pronunciation.

Hell (like it sounds) + of (pronounced like *ov-* on *oven*, or əv in IPA) + *a* (ə in IPA). Because the consonants are essentially *l* and *v*, it's easy to blend the words together: **hɛləvə**. Press on the audio icon to hear it pronounced [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=helluva&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Hell off a would require a voiceless fricative f, which is not present in *helluva*. To hear the voiceless fricative in *off*, use the audio icon [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/off).

There is no idiom, hell off a.  However, there is " to hell in a hand basket" which is fun. It means something is falling apart very quickly: *this plan of yours is going **to hell in a hand basket**.*

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Janus Bahs Jacquet, of course it comes from 'a hell of a'. In the UK, we still stay a hell of a, though said quickly, it can sound the same as 'helluva'. Here, though, it never appears in print in that way, but it does in the States, to it seems to be American shorthand for that phrase. In a similar vein, I've noticed something else happening the last ten years in the UK which is related - people  used to say 'I'm bored with....' or 'I'm fed up with....' something or other, and in speech, the words get run together so it sounds like 'I'm bored'v...' Now everyone actually says 'I'm bored of...' and 'fed up of',  losing entirely the original formulation of this expression. Which is presumably how 'helluva' came about...

Comment: Please could you provide evidence that any English-speaker reduces "with" to [v]? "bored of" and "fed up of" can be explained by analogy with "tired of".

Answer (score 0):

Its simply because "hell" is thought in the States as a mild cuss word. Whereas, in the UK it isn't. So we've always used "hell of a" and the Americans wrote it "heluva" to make it a non-cuss word. Simple!

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It is simply a not-so-commonly used slang. The meaning is the exact same as helluva, and should be interpreted as such.

Comment: Of course 'helluva' means the same as 'helluva'. It _is_ the same. And it's quite common.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U,rr. We appreciate your input. We also appreciate links to sources where applicable. :)

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet, I don't see how this was a bad answer. All I was doing was addressing the question. However, the only place I have seen it is on "helluva good!" onion dip. I would not exactly call helluva something that is commonly used.